# Timer_tick in c#

Tags: c#

How can I set my timer to work with seconds? When I use the timer from toolbox, without any changes it starts working with another time unit.
I will be grateful for any help which you can give me.

I have something like this:

```
t = 0; 
timer1.Start(); 
if (t == 600) 
    timer1.Stop();
```

Comment: I have something like this: t = 0;
timer1.Start();
if (t == 600)
   timer1.Stop();

Comment: Which timer are you using? Depending on what version of the framework and what application type you are using, there are, I think, three different timer components. One of them uses seconds as the interval, the rest use milliseconds.

Comment: The timer works with milliseconds (1000 milliseconds per second) and unfortunately cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
Use `timer.interval = 1000 * n;` where n is the number of seconds between the ticks.

Answer (score 3):

[Timer.Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) property takes the value in milliseconds. You should multiply your valued to 1000 to set the interval to seconds.

```
aTimer.Interval = 1*1000; // 1 second interval
aTimer.Interval = 2*1000; // 2 seconds interval
```

**Edit:**

If I understood correctly, you should register [Timer.Tick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) like

```
aTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
```

and check the value of `t` in its event handler. If `t == 600` then you can stop the timer

```
private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    ...
    t++;
    if(t == 600)
       aTimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

multiply the number of seconds you wish by 1000, it uses milliseconds out of the box

Answer (score 1):

The timer uses milliseconds as unit of time, you can do computation to fit your needs. In this case you want to delay in seconds, you can do something like:

```
int secondsInterval = 5;
timer.Interval = secondsInterval * 1000;
```

Hope this helps.